# query using data within and outside a filtered index

Tags: sql-server, filtered-index

If I have a filtered index, and if I use data beyond that range, what kind of performance hit would be incurred?

Comment: presumably that index will no longer be applicable, but depends....Why don't you try it and see turning on Actual Execution plan

Answer (score 2):

It will be the same as if the index did not exist. The exact impact on performance depends on your specific data.